# Aurelia page lifecycle - avoid user from leaving the page

Tags: aurelia

Giving the scenario where when leaving the page is losing unsaved data, the idea is to ask the user for a confirmation.

Using the `canDeactivate` hook I can easily avoid the user from leaving the page (I'm displaying a confirm dialog).

**However**, as soon the user press back on the **second** time, he can leave without a problem. It seems that the state is lost and the canDeactivate hook is no longer called.

*This applies to all pipeline steps (I tried then all, none safes the state after the first next.cancel)

Is there a  better way to avoid the user leaving the page?

```
canDeactivate() {

    return Promise.resolve(false);
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue a year later...